# .Net/WinForms Docking/Floating Library for .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, winforms, dockable

It must

1. Support .Net 4.0 Client Profile (designers in separate assembly)
2. Serialize layout to custom stream
3. Allow maximizing of floating window in caption doubleclick
4. Cost not too mush (200US$ is optimal). Also do not need a bundle of 1000 and 1 control.

I've already reviewed

- [DockPanel Suite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/)

  - 1 and 3 are violated. Also seems buggy (I easily crashed sample app).
- [SandDock](http://www.divelements.com/net/controls/sanddock/)

  - 1, 2, 3 are violated.
- [Nevron](http://www.nevron.com/Gallery.UserInterfaceFor.NET.DockingPanelsGallery.aspx)

  - 1, 3 are violated. Also works incorrectly in some multi-monitor scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out the [Krypton Suite](https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton).
You get the source code and you can compile against .NET 4